# How extend placeholder selector in Sass using @use rule

Tags: sass, node-sass

I have **_extandable.scss** file with one placeholder selector:

```css
%text-ellipsis {
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

and I'm trying to use it in another file:

```css
@use 'extendable';

.text-ellipsis {
  @extend extendable.%text-ellipsis;
}
```

The output of sass-loader is an error:

```
SassError: Expected identifier.
   ╷
4  │   @extend extendable.%text-ellipsis;
   │                      ^
   ╵
  src/assets/styles/_component.scss 4:22  @import
```

What's the right way of importing of placeholder selectors using @use rule?

Comment: Are you using Dart Sass or Node Sass?

Comment: @Arkellys node-sass. It's running in angular-cli

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After some investigation I've found out that it's incorrect syntax. Placeholder selectors have global scope during compiling, so we cannot write like this and we don't need to do it.